# Opening a docx document that is in a folder

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter, python-docx

I have looked all over for an answer and I can't find what I'm looking for and I'm sure it is simple.

Anyway I created a docx document with `python docx` and `tkinter`.  Everything works well there now I'm looking to open that file as soon as it is saved.   The only problem is I have no idea how to go about doing this.  My first thought was...

```
f = open("path\\"+name_created_by_python+".docx", mode="r")
```

But as some (or all) know that doesn't work for physically opening a document. Any suggestions.

UPDATE/CLARIFICATION: I want the code to save the doc (which it does) and then immediately open it up so the user can view it without having to physically go to the folder it is located. I suppose the code above "opens" it but doesn't really open it in the way that I want or need.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In what way did this not work?  I would expect it to worj, just not to be very useful, because `.docx` is a zipfile format.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html#really-opening-a-document)?

Comment: It doesn't work because it doesn't open the physical document.   I want the code to save the doc (which it does) and then immediately open it up so the user can view it without having to physically go to the folder it is located.  I suppose the code above "opens" it but doesn't really open it in the way that I want or need.   And yes I have looked at that document.

Comment: Just to clarify:  by saying  "open the document" you actually mean "launch an application so that the user can view the document", right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

So I found what I was looking for.  Below is the code required for windows.

```
import os

os.startfile("path"+filename+".docx")
```

The  +filename+ is the method used to give my docx document its specific name.